# Different way to register and unregistered broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying code for `LocalBroadcastManager`.While register and unregister `BroadcastReceiver` , I am using below code.

Can any one give difference between both way to register and unregister 
`LocalBroadcastManager`?

**First Way:**

```
...
//Register receiver
registerReceiver(mPairingReceiver, IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST"));
...
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
// unregister receiver
unregisterReceiver(mPairingReceiver);

}
```

**Second Way:**

```
...
//Register receiver
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(mPairingReceiver, IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST"));
...
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
// unregister receiver
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mPairingReceiver);

}
```

Comment: Why down vote? I am referring [registerReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), but I want know more about  why and where both are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first snippet calls `unregisterReceiver()` on a `Context`. This unregisters a receiver that you registered via `registerReceiver()` on the same `Context`. These methods are for system-level broadcasts.

Your second snippet calls `unregisterReceiver()` on a `LocalBroadcastManager`. This unregisters a receiver that you registered via `registerReceiver()` on the same `LocalBroadcastManager`. These methods are for local broadcasts, solely within your own application.

Comment: Thanks . I got difference between both